# GLSL Smoothly change temperature(color) of mesh over time

Tags: three.js, glsl

I am writing a small program using three.js.

I have rendered mesh from PLY object. And I want to heat polygons that are close to the mouse position. When I move mouse, all polygons near must smoothly change color to the red, and other polygons must smoothly return to their normal color over time.

I have succeeded in getting mouse position and changing color of the nearest polygons, but I don't know how to solve smooth fading over time for the other polygons.

Should I do it in shader or I should pass any additional data to the shader?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something simple like this (in a timer):

```
dtemp = Vertex_temp - background_temp;
Vertex_temp -= temp_transfer*dtemp*T/dt;
```

where `temp_transfer=<0,1>` is unit-less coefficient will adjust the speed of heat transfer. The `dt [sec]` is time elapsed (interval of your timer or update routine) and `T [sec]` is time scale for the `temp_transfer` coefficient.

So if your mouse is far than let `background_temp=0.0 [C]` and if not set it to `background_temp=255.0 [C]` now you can use the `Vertex_temp` directly to compute color ... using it as Red channel `<0,255>`

But as you can see this is more suited to do on CPU side instead of in GLSL because you need to update the color VBO each frame using its previous values... In GLSL you would need to encode it into texture or something and render back the new values into another one and then converting it back to VBO that is too complicated... maybe compute shader could do it in single pass but I am not familiar with those.